# Slice not working for pagination in Angular Material Angular 6

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

For some reason, my slice method isn't working when trying to paginate posts. Im using Angular Material and what i'm trying to do is be able to select how many posts I want to view on a page. I thought using the slice method would fix this but it is a persistent issue. Here is the relevant pieces of code.

register.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { PageEvent, MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: "app-register",
  templateUrl: "./register.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./register.component.css"]
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  showForm = localStorage.getItem("showForm") || false;
  name = localStorage.getItem("name");
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<object>;

  oops = false;
  posts = [];
  length;
  pageSize = 2;
  pageSizeOptions = [1, 2, 5, 10];
  pageIndex = 0;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    // db.list("/forum")
    //   .valueChanges()
    //   .forEach(val => {
    //     val.forEach(obj => {
    //       this.posts.push(obj);
    //     });
    //   });

    db.list("/forum")
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(array => {
        this.length = array.length;
      });

    db.list("/forum")
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(post => {
        this.posts = post;
      });
  }

  //functions to paginate posts
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  pageEvent: PageEvent;

  onPageChange(e) {
    this.pageIndex = e.pageIndex;
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
    this.loadData(this.pageIndex, this.pageSize);
  }

  loadData(pageIndex, pageSize) {
    console.log(pageIndex, pageSize);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<object>(
      this.posts.slice(pageIndex, pageIndex + pageSize)
    );
    // this.posts.slice(pageIndex, pageSize + pageSize);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.db
    //   .list("/forum")
    //   .valueChanges()
    //   .subscribe(post => {
    //     this.posts = post;
    //   });
    this.loadData(0, this.pageSize);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  //end of functions to paginate posts
}
```

register.component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">How are you?</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" (click)="submitPost()" class="btn btn-primary">
          Post
        </button>
      </form>
      <!-- <div class="adverts">
        <img src="../../assets/uber.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
      <p *ngFor="let post of posts.slice().reverse()" class="posts">
        {{ post.post }}
      </p>
      <!-- <table class="table" *ngFor="let post of posts.slice().reverse()">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th class="row"></th>
            <td>{{ post.post }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table> -->
      <mat-paginator
        [length]="length"
        [pageSize]="pageSize"
        [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
        (page)="onPageChange($event)"
      ></mat-paginator>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the page index and page size is working perfectly fine, and I console.loged it when angular enter loaddata and it is working fine. I think the problem is that angular is seeing the post array before its actually loaded. but then again when i console.log the posts array in my loaddata function, i can see the posts array with stuff in it. I really don't understand why my slice function isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. If there are any posts thats very closely related to mine please drop them. I've read multiple post but all were outdated and as I'm still learning I found it challenging to convert their code to mine. Like I said, any help is appreciated. Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Seems I should have been looping through dataSource. This brought on it's own unique challenges, but that's another topic for another post. Anyway, great day people.